# Stack Exchange site for phones

Tags: discussion, site-recommendation

I know about [Super User](http://www.superuser.com), but from all indications it is all about computer hardware.

Is there any Stack Exchange site where I can ask questions about problems on my phone?

Comment: If not, [create one](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/create?category=technology)!

Comment: What phone are you talking about? Nokia or Blackberry?

Comment: @random All types of phones but mine is samsung anyway

Comment: I wouldn't narrow it to phones, but rather Mobile Devices

Comment: Already Created : http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60741/mobile-devices

Comment: Cool, now you can answer your own question with this link

Comment: There's an [Android stackexchange](http://android.stackexchange.com/) with several Samsung tags.

Comment: @dcaswell My Phone is not android so my question might be off-topic for them

Comment: Sad that such as site has already gone into the works, it really should be based around general mobile devices, even things like all the off-brand tablets and why not even the Razor?

Comment: Of course I would expect such a site introduction would also require the migration of thousands of questions

Comment: Related discussion I just started: http://discuss.area51.stackexchange.com/questions/11988/should-this-mobile-devices-site-deserve-its-part-away-from-super-user

Comment: What's a phone?

Comment: @ColeJohnson Cell phone or Mobile phone or handset

Comment: Closely related, if not a duplicate: [Where should I ask questions about cell phones (problems with hardware, software, et cetera)?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/198298)

Comment: There's also: [Where can I ask about deleting call logs from a phone?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/147632) [Where would I ask a question about phone service technology?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132830)

Comment: @JerryDodge: There _was_ a "Gadgets" site meant to cover cell phones et al., but it died on the vine. Not focused enough. [Why is the Gadgets site deemed not viable?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/61593)

Answer (score 6):

The [existing StackExchange sites](https://stackexchange.com/sites) get much more attention than the Area51 proposals, so if your question fits anywhere on SE, post it there. For example, there is [Android.SE](https://android.stackexchange.com/) or [Apple.SE](https://apple.stackexchange.com/) (fine for iPhone questions; also gets much attention) or [Windows phone.SE](https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/).

On Area51, there <s>is</s> was a proposal for <s>[Mobile Devices](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60741/mobile-devices)</s> or <s>[Cell Phones](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/60023/cell-phones)</s>.